# C++ virtual Function complie Error

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, ref

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
 virtual void f4() { cerr << "A::f4()" << endl; }
}

class B : public A {
public:
 virtual void f4(int n) { cerr << "B::f4(" << n << ")" << endl; }
}

class C : public B {
public:
 virtual void f4(int n = 1) { cerr << "C::f4(" << n << ")" << endl; }
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;

    A& rab = b;     
    A& rac = c;     
    B& rbc = c;     

    rab.f4(); rac.f4(); rbc.f4(); 
}
```

When i run try to compile this code using **rab.f4(); rac.f4(); rbc.f4();** in the main method. **rbc.f4()** gives me a compiling error and it wont let me. can someone tell me the reason why?

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, always include the actual (complete and unedited) errors in the question body. Please edit your question to include your build log.

Comment: Separate those into three different lines. That will help you clearly see which call is problematic.

Comment: Though one problem might be that you don't actually override the *same* function. Remember that function arguments are part of the unique function signature.

Comment: And trying to call `B::f4` without any arguments won't work very well either.